# Auto resize for all images which have different sizes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, image-resizing, image-size

I have a imageshare.swf app. I taking pictures from "Images/"+imageNumber+".jpg" but, my all my pictures have different size. for example 970x700, 580*441, 500,500. I want to put them to stages with same size.(fixing 500x500 px).

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;



//*****************CREATING VARIABLES*****************************//

//the array has all picture labels
//var myGlow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter(0xffffff,1,10,10,255);// saving the glow
//var myShadow:DropShadowFilter = new DropShadowFilter(6);// saving the shadow to be applied later
var totalImages=11;
var imageNumber=1;

var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();


//************LOADING IMAGES TO STAGE********************//

var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Images/"+imageNumber+".jpg");
myLoader.load(myRequest);
addChildAt(myLoader,1);// will be added under the buttons layer but over the texture

//************CENTERING THE PICS****************//

myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, getImageInfo);
function getImageInfo(event:Event){
    var imgX=(stage.stageWidth- myLoader.width)/2;
    var imgY=(stage.stageHeight- myLoader.height)/2;
    myLoader.x=imgX;
    myLoader.y = imgY;// lines 37,38,39 & 40 are centering the loader formulae
    //myLoader.filters = [myGlow, myShadow];// adding a white color glow / grey shadow
    //var myTween:Tween = new Tween(myLoader, "alpha", None.easeNone, 0,1,2,true);//apply fade in

    }
//**************GOING TO NEXT IMAGE********************************//

rightButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextImage);
function nextImage(event:MouseEvent){
    if(imageNumber<totalImages)
    {
        imageNumber++;
    }
    else (imageNumber=1);
    reload();
    }
//**************GOING TO PREVIOUS IMAGE********************************//

leftButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, previousImage);
function previousImage(event:MouseEvent){
    if(imageNumber>1)
    {
        imageNumber--;
    }
    else (imageNumber=totalImages);
    reload();
    }

//*****************RELOADING****************************//
function reload(){
    removeChild(myLoader);
    myRequest= new URLRequest("Images/"+imageNumber+".jpg");
    myLoader.load(myRequest);
    addChildAt(myLoader,1);
    }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just where you set the `x` and `y` property, set `width` and `height`!

```
myLoader.width = myLoader.height = 500;
```

By the way, this will scramble those who are not perfectly squared and they will look distorted.

Comment: yes logically. I would like to ask another things. This URLrequest taking only pictures name like 1.jpg 2.jpg (var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Images/"+imageNumber+".jpg");) I want take also pictures which have different names like Slide1.jpg, Slide2.jpg(but numbers are important as you can see from codes)

Comment: Well then make other requests, that match your formula for creating URLs :)

Comment: Thank you Andrey. let me ask you one more question:). In my images file i have for example 11 images. i enter that number manually to the codes.(var totalImages=11;). How can I count them & write it automatically to var totalImages= ?